# How to make build failed in React Native project when ESLint emit error

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, eslint

As i see now, when eslint show error on console window. App keep continue update new code. I want to force it stop update latest code until no error appear and i dont want use VS Code Extension apply on project. 
Really appriciate when any one provide some clues.
Regard

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported eslint parameter to treat warnings as errors, but you can do something like this:

```
// .eslintrc.js
function isTruthy(value) {
  if (!value) return false;
  return ['1', 'true'].indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}

// Warnings are errors in CI
var OFF = 'off';
var ERROR = 'error';
var WARNING = isTruthy(process.env.CI) ? ERROR : 'warn';

module.exports = {
  // ...
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": OFF,
    "eqeqeq": [WARNING, "allow-null"],
    "import/imports-first": OFF,
    "indent": [WARNING, 2, {"SwitchCase": 1}],
    "max-len": [WARNING, 100, 2],
    "no-console": [WARNING, {"allow": ["warn", "error"]}],
    "no-debugger": WARNING,
    "no-fallthrough": WARNING,
    "no-unreachable": WARNING,
    "no-unused-vars": [WARNING, {"vars": "all", "args": "none"}],
    "no-var": ERROR,
    "prefer-const": WARNING,
    "react/prop-types": [WARNING, {"ignore": ["className"]}],
    "semi": [WARNING, "never"],
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: How's about eslint-loader ?